# Shared Folder don't share (Virtual Box) [Arch Linux]

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

**Windows: Host**

**Arch Linux: Guest**

I wanted to create a shared folder between Windows and Arch Linux, but I don't know why doesn't work because I can see the folder in `/media` in arch, but the files that copy there do not appear in the Windows folder

I did this

> Device > Insert Guest Adittions CD Image...

I opened a terminal where Guest Addition ... and i run this

```
 sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

next

```
 sudo pacman -S linux-headers virtualbox-guest-utils
 sudo systemctl enable vboxservice
```

then reboot and

> Deivce > Shared Folder > Shared Folder Settings ... > (in the right) Add Share (i choose folder path and automount) > OK

next

```
useradd -m -G vboxsf pedro
sudo chown -R pedro:users /media/sf_Public/
```

i can see the folder in `/media` in arch but when i copy a file or whatever don't appears in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still need the fix for this but i found the solution.

Once you have your user set up and you can see the shared folder, you need to change the permissions.

Your `chown` is incorrect.

You should use:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:vboxsf /mount/point/of/shared/folder
```